# What is wget idiom for curl -o?

Tags: bash, shell, wget, curl

So I use code in some function like

```
if [ ! -e $DOWNLOADS/$1 ]; then
    echo_run curl -L http://$4/$5/$1 -o $DOWNLOADS/$1
fi
```

I wonder how to achieve the same thing without curl?

Answer (score 7):

Dixit `man wget`:

```
   -O file
   --output-document=file
       The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together
       and written to file.  If - is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output,
       disabling link conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)

       Use of -O is not intended to mean simply "use the name file instead of the one in the URL;"
       rather, it is analogous to shell redirection: wget -O file http://foo is intended to work like
       wget -O - http://foo > file; file will be truncated immediately, and all downloaded content will
       be written there.
```

Comment: Just curious, what is the meaning of "dixit"?

Comment: @jw013: in this context, it's roughly "thus says". It's an allusion to "Dixit Algorismi", an early manuscript on arithmetic; i.e. a quote from authorative work.